# C# Asynchronous socket Sent and Received callback

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, callback

I have a class (AsyncClient) which is able to send and receive data using a TCP/IP socket. This class uses asynchronous socket methods in order to better handle errors and to avoid threads.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

### Connect method

```cs
    private Socket _socket;
    private byte[] _receivedDataBuffer;
    private byte[] _sentDataBuffer;

    public void Connect(IPEndPoint serverEndPoint)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the socket object
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _socket.Blocking = false;

            //Connect to server
            _socket.BeginConnect(serverEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnected), _socket);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
             //Handle error
        }
    }

    private void OnConnected(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        //Socket was the passed in object
        Socket socket = (Socket)Result.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            socket.EndConnect(Result);
            if (socket.Connected) //Check if we were sucessfull
            {
                //Setup receive callback
                _receivedDataBuffer = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                socket.BeginReceive(_receivedDataBuffer, 0, _receivedDataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), socket);

                //Raise "Connected" event on UI thread
            }
            else
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
             //Handle error
        }
    }
```

### Data received callback

```cs
    private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        //Sometimes, this occurs before the DataSent callback
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.fff"));

        //Socket was the passed in object
        Socket socket = (Socket)Result.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            int received = socket.EndReceive(Result);
            if (received > 0)
            {
                //Store received data

                //Raise "DataReceived" event on UI thread

                //Restablish the callback
                socket.BeginReceive(_receivedDataBuffer, 0, _receivedDataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), socket);
            }
            else
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
             //Handle error
        }
    }
```

### Send method and DataSent callback

```cs
    public void SendData(byte[] Data)
    {
        _sentDataBuffer = Data;
        _socket.BeginSend(_sentDataBuffer, 0, _sentDataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnDataSent), _socket);
    }

    private void OnDataSent(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        //Sometimes, this occurs after the DataReceived callback
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.fff")); 

        //Socket was the passed in object
        Socket socket = (Socket)Result.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            int sent = socket.EndSend(Result);
            if(sent > 0)
            {
                //Raise "DataSent" event on UI thread
            }
            else
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

### My issue

I use this class in order to send data to a server which answers **almost instantaneously**.
Thus, when I use the "SendData" method, sometimes everything works as expected:

1. The data I sent is received by the remote server
2. Then the DataSent callback is executed
3. The remote server send back an acknowledgement
4. Then the DataReceived callback which gets the ACK is executed

But for some reason, sometimes, when I use the "SendData" method, I have the following behavior:

1. The data I sent is received by the remote server
2. The remote server send back an acknowledgement
3. Then the DataReceived callback which gets the ACK is executed
4. Then the DataSent callback is executed

In the second case, I don't understand why the DataReceived callback occurs before the DataSent callback (from 1 to 10ms before). Can you help me to fix this ? Thank You.

Comment: It seems to be a race condition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: You designed it as async, so you get async events.  What is your problem?  What you are describing is not abnormal.

Comment: @MartinJames This is the answer that I expected to have. But still, it is a bit odd. Does it means that the only solution to my problem is to use synchronous sockets?

Comment: I can not believe that I am the firt one having this issue. There must be a solution.

Comment: @Brice - why does there need to be a solution?  What do you do in in the DataSent callback that is sensitive to the event sequencing?  I mean, if you are just deleting or repooling some 'used' send buffer object, whay does it matter when that happens?

Comment: @MartinJames I am developping a messaging app (like SMS apps). Thus, the DataSent callback is used to raise an event which will cause the display of an UI element (a speech bubble which contains the data). The DataReceived callback is also used for the same purpose. The problem is that my UI displays the message received before the message sent. So it is really confusing for the user. (Indeed, for an SMS app, you expect to see the message you sent before/above the message you've received and not the reverse)